# Reference a function inside an object from another function inside the same object. JavaScript object literal form

Tags: javascript

In the code below when I try to call `promptUpdater` function from inside `userInputOn` function in the `ArrayRotation` object, I get a *TypeError: Cannot read property promptUpdater of undefined.*

I guess, its the last line of the code `rotationTaskObj.userInputOn();` where I need to correct reference, but I am not able to do it.

```
'use strict';

 var ArrayRotation = {
   arr : [],

   promptUpdater : function() {
     //code
   },

   userInputOn : function() {
     return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       this.promptUpdater(); //correct way to reference promptUpdater fn?
     });
    },
  }

 let rotationTaskObj = Object.create(ArrayRotation);

 let userInputPr = rotationTaskObj.userInputOn(); //My guess, I need to create correct refernce here, not able to get how to do that?
```

What is the correct way to reference `promptUpdater` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is where you are trying to call `this.promptUpdater()`, `this` isn't what you think it is.  `this` is scoped to the current function, which is your `function(resolve, reject)`, not your object.

**Traditional function method with `.bind`**

If you don't want to use arrow functions (you should, but I won't judge :-)), you can set a function's `this` value using the `bind()` method:

To change `userInputOn` to bind it's this to it's parent's `this`:

```
   userInputOn : function() {
       return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
           this.promptUpdater(); //correct way to reference promptUpdater fn?
       }.bind(this));
   },
```

**Arrow function method**

Change

```
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
```

To

```
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
```

Arrow functions don't have a `this` like normal functions, they pick up the `this` from the hosting function.

Here's a fiddle:"  https://jsfiddle.net/jmbldwn/fpa9xzw0/5/

Comment: I got the expected output with fat arrow function. On the contrary, the whole idea is not to mix traditional this binding with fat arrow lexical binding.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with the `this` reference getting "lost" inside the Promise's callback function. There are a number of fixes, but the easiest as of ES6 is to use an arrow function instead:

```
new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {this.promptUpdateUser();})
```